# When do six operations work?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, six-operations, homological-algebra

This question comes (heavily edited) from my notes, thus slightly unusual structure.

---

We know that algebraic maps have very strict structure, and in many settings the operations `f_*`, `f_!`, their adjoints `f^*`, `f^!`, bioperations ⊗ and `=>`  as well as duality `D` behave well. They satisfy (whenever defined) some good identities, especially for proper morphisms.

There are specific subtleties in the following cases:

- case **Z**: constructible sheaves `:=` (finite) local systems (finitely) glued  ...
- case *O*: coherent sheaves `:=` finitely generated *O*-modules ...
- case **D**: (D-modules) holonomic `:=` 'number of equations is just right' ...

> **Question:** I wonder if there are other sheaves of non-commutative algebras for which we can define operations and duality? That is, is it possible to continue this list with another "case **?**".

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0573/) article of Fausk, Hu and May adds nothing to the list but gives a very nice analysis of the categorical situations in which you have six operations.